# Download files from git repo on linux server

Tags: linux, git, bash, github, continuous-deployment

I have seen so many articles/questions on how to download specific files from git repo, but none of them seems to match with my case.

---

- What I need

---

Download spefic files from private git repository either using http's or ssh from linux server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - I originally wrote this as a general answer about git, and will preserve that info below.  But I see you're talking about github, which does give some additional options.

For example, you could use a command like

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/master/README.md > README.md
```

to download just the README.md from the frontend-maven-plugin (which I happen to be looking at just now).

You mention yours is a private repo, so you'd have to deal with authentication; I suggest reading up on `curl`, as it should be able to provide credentials to the repo.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

**Original answer**

There's not really a single git command for downloading an individual file from within a remote git repo.  The closest I know you can do is this:

First clone the repo without checking out a work tree

```
git clone -n <repo-url>
```

Then check out just the file you want

```
git checkout master -- path/within/repo/to/file
```

But don't be fooled:  This still downloads the entire repo.  (That's just how git works.)  So in addition to getting ./path/within/repo/to/file you also got ./.git containing all the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this hackish way: ö(å_å)ö

*If this file is on github.com do this.:*

```
wget https://example.githubproject.com/user/project/master/README
```

You can try **git archive command**:

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)
```

Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the current branch, and extract it in the /var/tmp/junk directory.

**Example git archieve command usage:**

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=origin HEAD | tar xf -
git archive --format=tar --remote=origin HEAD <file> | tar xf -
```

Tip in using, [git archive](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html), [Examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what about your question is, but, have you did `git clone <<url of git project>>` ??

Comment: question : I need to download specific files from git repository from linux server to a specific directory

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more [rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) you will be able to post comments

Comment: Sorry @LibinVarghese